# Curating the homepage

Tags: craft-features

Learning Craft currently. Wondering if there's any plugin that simplifies the curation of the home page by allowing pinning a post, highlighting a post, reordering a post etc (non chronologically)

Here's a reference of a equivalent Wordpress plugin:
https://github.com/10up/curator

THanks

Answer (score 3):

You could create a matrix content field for the homepage with a child entry selection field. You can add as many matrix blocks as you'd like, and select the entries you would like within them.

You can read more about Matrix fields [here](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/matrix-fields).

Likewise you can checkout entry field types [here](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/entries-fields).

So your code for `index.twig` might look like:

```
{% for block in entry.calloutBlocks %}
  <article>
    {{block.title}}
    {{block.body}}
    <a href="{{block.url}}">Read more</a>
  </article>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks @rob Will try out what you suggested. So there's no plugin I presume at the moment.

Comment: That's whats great about Craft; a lot of features don't require plugins. A lot of it can be done with core functionality out of the box. This has tons of benefits: 1. You can write the exact markup you need, 2. You can use the exact styles you need without any extra bloat, 3. You know *exactly* how something functions, without any magical undocumented functions.